# What are the effects of changing the bundle id, App Id and App name for an app live on the app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Suppose I have an iOS app live on the app store with an App Id (and app bundle Id) of `com.mycompany.my-cool-app` and an App Name of `My Cool App`.

Now I want to change my App Id to `com.newcompany.my-interesting-app` and App Name to `My Interesting App`.

I've never done this but I think the steps would be:

1. Change the bundle Id in Xcode.
2. Create a new App Id in developer.apple.com.
3. In the Apps Provisioning Profile on developer.apple.com change the App Id to the new App Id
4. Change the App name in Xcode, increment the version number and upload new App to iTunes connect where I can then change the App name in iTunes connect and submit the app for review.

My question is: 
What are the implications of doing this?

1. What happens to users who have the app currently installed on their phone? Would they have to re-download the app since so much underlyingly has changed or would they just get the new app with the new app name upon updating the app?
2. Since the bundle Id changed, would there be an issue in accessing files/photos saved in the documents directory from the previous version?
3. What else could go "wrong"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change the bundle id of an existing app. The bundle id *is* the app. If you change the bundle id, that is a whole new and different app. So, do what you like, as long as you keep that basic fact in mind.

What I have seen done in a similar situation is that the developer issues a final version of the old app which knows how to export the data to the new app. Marvin and GoodReader are cases in point.

Comment: I have never done it, but there seem to be many answers on SO explaining how to chance the bundle Id of an app in Xcode. Are you saying that you cannot chance the bundle Id of an existing app live the app store (e.g. in iTunes connect)?

Comment: "there seem to be many answers on SO explaining how to chance the bundle Id of an app in Xcode" But not once it has started being distributed by the app store, surely? "Are you saying that you cannot chance the bundle Id of an existing app live the app store (e.g. in iTunes connect)?" Exactly. If I've misunderstood the situation, just tell me and I'll delete my answer! But you did say "Suppose I have an iOS app live on the app store with an App Id (and app bundle Id) of...", so I supposed that.

Comment: No your answer is what I was looking for. Maybe I am just a pedantic for complete sentences since sometimes people answer questions on SO which could be interpreted one of two ways if you never read the question (And sometimes other viewers do not read the question). Thank you sir!